# Using GPU with Torch7 on iOS

Tags: ios, deep-learning, torch

I checked torch7 for ios https://github.com/clementfarabet/torch-ios
I could not find anywhere mentioned if torch 7 for ios uses GPU. I checked the example projects XOR_Example... It includes Accelerate framework, which I guess uses CPU only. I could not see Metal framework being used. Does this mean Torch 7 does not use GPU on ios? If yes, what are other options to for deploying a NN on ios (for inference) that uses GPU?